# How long does memsql upgrade takes?

Tags: singlestore

I have started an offline upgrade process to upgrade my MemSql Cluster from 5.8 To 6.5, Data size is around 300G it's been 5 hours already but i have lost all access to cluster and also there is no way to check the status.

memsql-ops memsql-list returns all leaves and aggregator shows online.
But, memsql> SHOW LEAVES; return empty set, my master aggregator automatically converted to child aggregator, so now i don't have any master aggregator.

I can't execute any command (Like AGGREGATOR SET AS MASTER) to child aggregator, it says 'memsql is not running as an aggregator', Or 'memsql node is not running', and sql query returns "The database 'xxx' is not available for queries, as it is waiting for the Master Aggregator to bring it online.  Run SHOW DATABASES EXTENDED ..."

Also performing any management command like memsql-ops restart returns "Job cannot run because there is a MemSql upgrade intention with ID xxx is in progress"

Any information about this will be helpful as i am not able to find any related information online.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you get the output of `memsql-ops agent-list` and `memsql-ops memsql-list`? What are the versions?

Comment: Yes, i am able to get output, agent version is 6.5.8 And memsql version is 6.5.9.

Comment: Its likely faster to debug this on our public slack at chat.memsql.com (to avoid too much back and forth collecting information)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We debugged the issue in MemSQL public chat and it was found that the Master Agg was running an unsupported beta version of MemSQL (6.0.0) which prevented the upgrade and then corrupted the database post upgrade.

For future readers please audit that you are **not** running beta versions of MemSQL on production clusters.  If you are, not only will upgrade likely break, but it may not be possible to recover your data on a non-beta cluster.

Comment: To add to that, note that most beta versions of MemSQL explicitly disallow upgrading to and from that version, including this one.